# Readonly table/entity EF Core 3.0

Tags: entity-framework-core, ef-core-3.0

Is it possible to make a table/entity in EF Core 3.0? Basically i have history tables on which i want to ristrict insert/update/delete commands.

I already tried AsNoTracking by changing:

```
public DbSet<SampleHistory> SampleHistories { get; set; }
```

to:

```
public IQueryable<SampleHistory> SampleHistories { get {return Set<SampleHistory>).AsNoTracking<SampleHistory>(); } }
```

It works fine if i do something like this (nothing gets saved in DB):

```
var v = DbContext.SampleHistories.FirstOrDefault(e => e.HistoryId == 1);
v.Field1 = $"Test{DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString()}";
DbContext.SaveChanges();
```

but if i add Update statment before save, i see record getting updated in DB:

```
var v = DbContext.SampleHistories.FirstOrDefault(e => e.HistoryId == 1);
v.Field1 = $"Test{DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString()}";
DbContext.Update(v);
DbContext.SaveChanges();
```

I want to avoid that too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this requirement by enforing such tables to get generated as Views.

Ex:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<SampleHistory>(eb =>
        {
            eb.HasNoKey();
            eb.ToView("Sample_History");
        .
        .
        .
        });
```

EF thows Invalid operation exception if you try to perform Insert, Update, or Delete operation on such tables.